# How to start a .desktop application from the applications screen

Tags: .desktop, gnome-shell

I created a bunch of `.desktop` launchers (I believe is the proper term) which are extremely easy to find using the applications search bar (<kbd>Windows</kbd>/<kbd>super</kbd> key). Unfortunately when clicked they just open up in gedit.

I saw other questions that describe how to run the `.desktop` file through the terminal by grep-ing `Exec=...` but that doesn't really make much sense to me as I could just run the contained commands, why would I need a `.desktop` file in the first place?

Comment: IIRC in some locations they need to have execute permission set, for instance in user's home folder, otherwise they're treated as plain text. It was in Ubuntu specs somewhere, but they do work otherwise in Desktop folder. Try moving it there or just `chmod +x` them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put all the `.desktop` launchers in your `~/.local/share/applications` directory (note that `~/` corresponds to your home directory).

Then the associated applications will appear in your "Show Applications" list and you'll be able to launch them, if not then you should re-login or reboot (or simply restart GNOME shell by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and then typing `r` and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>).

Comment: I came across an answer that also suggested that and it didn't work. However just for the sake of it now I tried it again and it works, explain this...

Comment: @php_nub_qq Magic! ;-)

Comment: @php_nub_qq Joking aside, you probably just needed to re-login or restart the GNOME shell once at the time it didn't work.

Comment: Yep, I just realized that as at the time I wrote the comment I had only added 1, then I created a sub-folder and added many and none of them showed up, so I just rebooted and that solved the problem. It's probably worth adding to the answer as someone else who's ADD is as bad as mine would also think it does not work.

Comment: Simply restarting GNOME Shell with Alt-F2 and `r` should be enough.